# Waiting for localhost, forever!

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have a gridview on my homepage with a view and an edit link that use query strings to display table data in read-only and editable pages, respectively. I get no error messages from my code, it's simple enough that it doesn't seem to be missing anything, but when I try to debug or view in browser, I get the permanent pinwheel on my status bar and the message "waiting for localhost". What am I missing? Does anyone out there have some experience with this particular issue? I'm using C# and ASP.NET in visual studios with sql server 2008.

Comment: I've found this exact same problem today - looking forward to the answers

Comment: You can try taking a look at IIS logs and SQL Server logs to see what's happening. You can also try turning on ASP.NET tracing. You can also use fiddler to see what's going on with your request. No, I didn't have that problem ever :)

Comment: Could be an endless loop in your code. Try breaking in VS and see what's running.

Comment: HAHAHAHA!! Oh microsoft, we love to hate you. My trainer came up with a brilliant solution, demonstrating the principle of Foreman's Law (faulty machines won't work until you tell the foreman they don't, and then he/she comes to check them): he shut down VS2010 and restarted it. Problem solved. It's a banner day for my ego, guys. Keep calm and carry on.

Comment: always always try a technical reboot! :)

Comment: This has been terrorizing me for a couple years now. Lately it's gotten worse. Sadly none of the workarounds currently in this thread fix the problem. I've tried it all: restart VS, restart IIS, restart SQL, reset/change AppPools, use localhost, don't use localhost, toggle VPN, etc ... nothing seems to truly fix or remedy the issue consistently. For now  the only solution have is restarting my machine (VM) but that of course takes a painful 5-10 mins to get all the way back up.  
Anyhow - if anyone has any other solutions please do share. Obv if I find one I'll share as well.

Comment: I am using entity framework and Database service was down and I made it up and the projuext start working.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

My trainer came up with a brilliant solution, he shut down VS 2010 and restarted it. Problem solved.

Comment: I know it seems to be an IT joke but its amazing how many times switching it off and on again fixes things

Comment: In my case, restarting Visual Studio didn't work, but restarting the machine did work. Maybe restarting the browser would have been enough.

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio (VS) also works fine when I use VS Community 2019 and follow the tutorial "Create your first ASP.NET Core web app", https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-aspnet-core-ef-step-02?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 11):

Almost sounds like the database connection is going off neverland.

If your timeout on the connection and/or command is set pretty high, like 300 (which is 5 minutes) then it would appear to just hang forever if it is unable to make that connection.

The first thing I'd try is to set the connection timeout to something reasonable like 15 seconds in the web.config.

Then I'd run it again.

Assuming you get a connection failure, I'd use another tool to try and connect to the database using the settings in your web.config.

Answer (score 3):

Does this only happen on debug (ie F5)?

If that is the case, my guess is that you are hitting a breakpoint?

If you hit a break point, the browser appears to be dead... but in fact VS is waiting on you to respond...

Answer (score 3):

I found that creating a new app pool, then assigning the (already created) web site to it resolved this.

Answer (score 2):

I shut down iis, stopped debugging the site in visual studio, and restarted with F5 ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to not use localhost but your local ip address.

Comment: I tried this and got "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory"        Is this related? any idea on how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same thing happen; If you are on a VPN connection, you may need to change your web.config file to use your database IP instead of the name (if you have DNS issues with VPN). This won't help the OP but someone else may find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

This one may seem strange, but it might be caused if you're downloading torrents and your database is on a different server. This seemed to be my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but it was not solved by restarting Visual Studio, or by finding an endless loop. My issue was caused by user authentication failure.

Yesterday I published a web app to my company's server. IT set up the windows authentication for me with IIS, which they did with administrator rights. When I tried to debug my code afterwards I did not have a valid username/password. 
Instead of just giving a run-time error, the page loaded continuously.

My solution was to comment out the identity line in the web.config file.

```
    //Comment out the line below
    <identity impersonate="true" password="example" userName="domainName\administrator">
```

Answer (score 0):

If by mistake console.writeline()is used in webform instead of Response.writeline or use console.readline ()  methods then webform will never display the output and will do processing for ever.

Answer (score 0):

I spent SO many hours on this with none of the many suggestions on the web working.

For me... something was causing the file: **app_offline.html** to be written to the root directory of my project.  Instead of showing me the message that the application had been taken offline, etc., it just waited forever with message "waiting on local host".

I removed the file and it suddenly was working again.

Answer (score 0):

My problem occurred because I had an extra character in `web.config`.

When I opened up a view it couldn't recognize `@model` and when hovering over it said where the problem in the `web.config` was.

Answer (score 0):

From a similar question: [asp.net waiting for localhost forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656654/asp-net-waiting-for-localhost-forever)

> Check firewall for blocked ports, change dynamic ports of application
>   to some fixed port.

Changes in Firewall settings may be a leading cause.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was deleting the hidden `.vs` folder from the root solution directory