# Localhost waiting forever for ASP.NET 5 Application template project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, localhost

I'm trying to start a new ASP.NET 5 project using Visual Studio Community 2015. After I create a project using the ASP 5 Web Application template and run it, 99% of the time the browser will say "Waiting for localhost..." and nothing will happen. I say 99%, because at some very random times it has actually worked and loaded without me having done anything differently.

If I try doing exactly the same but using an empty project instead, I get no issues and it runs fine. However, I'd rather use the template, and in any case, I'd like to know what is causing this issue to avoid future problems.

What could be causing this issue? I already looked at [asp.net waiting for localhost forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27656654/asp-net-waiting-for-localhost-forever) and every other related question without any luck.

EDIT - This is how bizarre this is: I created a ASP.NET 5 project with the Web Application template, which got stuck in "Waiting for localhost..." every time. After that, I restarted the computer and tried again, and it worked fine (every time, it always works from now on). However, if I copy and paste the whole project folder to any other location (even in the same folder the working project is sitting at) and try running it, it will not work. There's absolutely no differece between the projects as I'm just copying and pasting the folder. What's going on?

Comment: what about debugging? any clue about where the code actually stops waiting forever?

Comment: Right after calling public IActionResult Index() { return View(); } in the HomeController.

Comment: Could it be the model that can't be created? Is LocalDB/SQLExpress set up correctly? If you created the Project from the template it'll add identity to it, and it will attempt to create the database for the Project on first start.
Have you updated your templates to the latest version or are you using the vs2015 default ones?

Comment: @EricJohansson I would assume that if there was any issue creating the model I would a) get some kind of error instead of the view never showing and b) have the same issue happening to all the copies of the project. Anyhow, how do I check if that is the issue? Regarding the templates, I've used the ones that came with VS Community 2015, which I installed about a month ago so I would have thought they'd be the latest.

Comment: @EricTrigo, go to http://www.asp.net/vnext and download the latest beta(beta7) of the asp.net 5 preview. You're currently using beta1, which is what ships with VS2015 until asp.net 5 goes RTM. Also, check under server explorer and see if you can find a database with your project name there.

Comment: Do you have any firewall or antivirus installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Browser Link feature may be causing you issues. Please see [this](http://www.poconosystems.com/software-development/how-to-disable-browser-link-in-visual-studio-2013/) for disabling browser link. Even though the link mentions, VS 2013, its same VS 2015. When I started using VS 2015, I faced a really slow loading of the web applications while debugging. I haven't faced your second scenario though.

Comment: I expected it to be something really stupid, but not this stupid. Wow. Thanks!