# How can I restart IIS Express within Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, iis-express

We are currently heavily tweaking applicationhost.config files within our Visual Studio solutions in order to get additional host header bindings up and running.

Is there a way to quickly restart IIS Express from Visual Studio without having to start a debug session? The changes in applicationhost.config are only picked up after a restart.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can close it on the *system tray* or killing its process at the *Task Manager* and to run it again you just need to use iisexpress exe, it's usually at `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe` or `C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe` if you use 32bit Windows.

Comment: or just run the website again in visual studio to restart it back again.

Answer (score 7):

**Option 1:**

1. Right Click on IISExpress icon in system tray
2. Click on name of running project
3. Click "Stop Site"

[image]

**Option 2:**

1. Open Task Manager (Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>)
2. Right Click on 'iisexpress.exe'
3. Click 'End process tree'

[image]