# why are my changes not detected in visual studio2022

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2022

I faced a problem while working on MVC project in visual studio2022. when I change anything in my CSS folder, the change does not appeare and when I run the project it shows my previous style

I searched a lot , but I could not fix it .does anyone show me a solution to solve this problem?

Comment: Sometimes IIS Express can be a problem, try and reset it... [how-can-i-restart-iis-express-within-visual-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42003899/how-can-i-restart-iis-express-within-visual-studio)

Comment: Could be a browser cache, have you tried open in an anonymous tab or reload with Shift+F5?

Comment: You should detail what exactly you've tried to do so far (i.e. cleared browser cache, ran in incognito mode, etc...) to help others help you.