# Inconsistent debugging of MVC app on localhost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, localhost

I have a problem with debugging on local host, I cannot resolve it neither by restarts or reconnecting to networks etc.

I cannot solve it with solutions from here:
[Waiting for localhost, forever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704780/waiting-for-localhost-forever)

(The project used to work, then I left it for two weeks and 'something' must have changed).

The symptoms are following - in Firefox, it says waiting for localhost forever, in Internet Explorer it waits a while and then shows an InternalServerError 500.

In VS 2015 it says that it's loading various assemblies (Owin etc) and it takes a VERY long time, but regardless, when the loading finishes and VS says it's Ready, it still does not work.

I am not hitting a breakpoint nor an endless loop.

I have two applications that I test, one uses port 62331, other one uses 44300. The one that uses 62331 works OK, the other one does not.
PortQry says both ports are listetning:
[image]
[image]

I have noticed that I have 4 IIS processes active in 'Processes' tab, not sure if that's right or not...

Please let me know what can I check or how can I try to fix it.

Comment: Have you checked your IIS logs? Is this possibly some sort of IIS level redirect loop going on.?

Comment: Not debug your app, just run it using "start without debugging", how about the result? Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings, enable the exception thrown option, do you get any detailed exception messages? As you said that the symbols loaded take long time, you could disable it under TOOLS->Options->Debugging->Symbols.

Comment: @JackZhai - without debugging it starts OK...

Comment: @Bartosz，do you debug it in other VS machine? Put a watch on “this.Context.AllErrors” which allow you to debug each request until you get the error in the AllErrors property: http://gavindraper.com/2013/06/22/asp-net-mvc-debugging-internal-server-error-500/. Maybe you could get more detailed error. Please also make sure that it is not the Browser issue or the settings under project properties->Web, you could troubleshoot or compare it using a simple MVC app.

Comment: @Bartosz, what about this issue? Any updates?

Comment: @JackZhai - I ended up redownloading the project from TFS and it somehow started working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**>>I ended up redownloading the project from TFS and it somehow started working**

Maybe the previous project was not the latest version from the server or others, anyway, since this question has been resolved,  I just help you post the comment as the answer here.