# django: Localhost stopped working suddenly?

Tags: django, local

I'm truing to run  a django server and all of a sudden I'm not able to go 
to `localhost:8000`. I was able to a few seconds back, but now now it's just freezing up and saying "waiting for localhost"

I'm on a Mac OS X

How do I debug this?

Comment: have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: @Vnc I tried clearing my cache, that didn't work - the problem persists. I'll try restarting my Mac...

Answer (score 1):

Some links:

[Waiting for localhost : getting this message on all browsers](https://serverfault.com/questions/943959/waiting-for-localhost-getting-this-message-on-all-browsers)

[Waiting for localhost, forever!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704780/waiting-for-localhost-forever)

[Why does my machine keeps waiting for localhost forever?](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-my-machine-keeps-waiting-for-localhost-forever)

To summarise it - in general it means that the 1) server is waiting for input (e.g. not returning a response), 2) some other service might be running on the same port, 3) no DB connection.

However, that said a restart should sort all these out by killing all processes that might've taken the port and by restarting the DB and reconnecting properly.

[image]